# preventing facebook from caching images in static fbml tab application

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have a static FBML application.  In the application, I have an image tag that points to am ImageGenerator web service that provides different images randomly.

I noticed though Facebook was caching the image in the src tag.  How do I update this on tab load so that it forces FB to retrieve the new image?

I heard something about fb:ref, but I am not sure how to do this programatically in a static FBML application.

Answer (score 0):

I thing these two links have a wide discussion on your problem related stuff. fb:ref clear cashes by calling

```
fbml.refreshRefUrl
```

like this

```
<tt>fbml.refreshRefUrl("http://www.mysite.com/someurl.php")</tt>
```

You can study the related stuff from here
[fb:ref](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ref/). I hope it will work for you